# ¿Por qué cuando retrocedo con el navegador en mi proyecto de laravel y vuejs enves de mostrarme la vista normal me muestra los datos en Json?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, google-chrome

Estoy por terminar un proyecto en laravel y vuejs, pero desde hace tiempo se me ha venido presentando el problema de que cuando le doy para atras con el navegador no me muestra la vista como tal sino que me muestra los datos en formato json. Este problema me sucedia desde antes de integrarle vuejs al proyecto, cuando solo utilizaba las plantillas de blade con laravel, ahora practicamente la mayoria de las peticiones las hago con ajax en componentes de vuejs utilizando axios y el problema sigue igual. El proyecto es muy extenso por lo que no se que partes del codigo debo mostrarles, pero a continuacion les voy a mostrar unas imagenes de cuando me sucede el problema:

Esta es l vista principal:
[image: Imagen de la vista principal]
Y esta es una vista cualquiera de ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando le doy para atras desde la vista de ejemplo hacia la principal con chrome me pasa lo siguiente:
[image: Imagen del error]

Y esto sucede en la mayoria de las vistas del proyecto (no en todas).

Cabe destacar que el problema se me presenta tanto cuando le doy hacia adelante como hacia atras en google chrome, y lo probe en microsoft edge y en ese navegador no se me presenta este problema.

Cuando recargo la pagina de nuevo si se muestra de manera normal.

Ahora, mi pregunta es, ¿Ese problema seguira ocurriendo cuando suba mi aplicacion a un servidor de produccion? ¿Y si es así, cual podría ser el causante de ese problema?

Comment: Interesante, mira si tus configuraciones de rutas están bien. ¿Es una SPA?

Comment: No es una SPA al 100% porque el routing que se esta utilizando es el de Laravel, pero algunas vistas tienen componentes de VueJS que si funcionan como una SPA

Comment: Supongo que son solicitudes get la que se muestran así

Comment: Ya realicé el despliegue de mi aplicación web en un VPS, y este problema se sigue presentando. Para quienes quieran ver el problema pueden hacer la prueba ustedes mismos, el dominio es trainingnutrition.org

Answer (score 3):

Ya encontré cual era el origen del problema.

En el controlador estaba utilizando la misma función para retornar la vista y recibir la petición ajax que realizan los componentes de Vue.JS de dicha vista, lo cual provocaba el problema.

```
public function categoria($slug, Request $request)
{
    $category = Categoria::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

    if ($request->ajax()) {

        $articlesCount = $category->posts()->count();
        $consultsCount = $category->consultations()->count();

        $res = [
            'category' => $category,
            'articlesCount' => $articlesCount,
            'consultsCount' => $consultsCount
        ];

        return response()->json($res, 200);
    }

    return view('categories.show', compact('category'));
}
```

Lo único que tuve que hacer fue separar la petición ajax a otra funcion diferente a la que retorna la vista, y luego desde el componente hacer dicha petición a una url que utilice esa función nueva:

Función que retorna la vista:

```
public function categoria($slug, Request $request)
{
    $category = Categoria::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

    return view('categories.show', compact('category'));
}
```

Función para realizar petición AJAX:

```
public function categoria($slug, Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {

        $category = Categoria::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

        $articlesCount = $category->posts()->count();
        $consultsCount = $category->consultations()->count();

        $res = [
            'category' => $category,
            'articlesCount' => $articlesCount,
            'consultsCount' => $consultsCount
        ];

        return response()->json($res, 200);
    }
}
```